# Neo4j Error: Node xxx has already been deleted in this transaction

Tags: neo4j, cypher

It seems that this cypher code would cause this error: Node xxx has already been deleted in this transaction.

```
MATCH (a:Address), (b:Address), (a)-[r:BelongTo]->(:Wallet), (b)-[:BelongTo]->(:Wallet)
WHERE a.AddId=b.AddId AND ID(a) > ID(b)

WITH r, a, b, a {.*, rel: r {.*, type:type(r)}} as snapshot
DELETE r
WITH a, b, snapshot     ------------------*
DELETE a                -------------------*
WITH b, snapshot

MERGE (c:Address {uniqueReferenceAddr:(...)})
ON CREATE SET c.AddId=snapshot.AddId,..."            
WITH c, b, snapshot
MATCH (wa:Wallet) WHERE snapshot.rel.primWallAddr=wa.primWallAddr
MERGE (c)-[r:BelongTo{uniqueReferenceBelongTo:(c.AddId + wa.primWallAddr)}]->(wa)
ON CREATE SET r.primWallAddr = wa.primWallAddr
WITH c, b 
MATCH (b)-[r0:BelongTo]->(wa:Wallet)
WITH wa, c, b, r0
MERGE (c)-[r1:BelongTo{uniqueReferenceBelongTo:(c.AddId + wa.primWallAddr)}]->(wa)
ON CREATE SET r1.primWallAddr = wa.primWallAddr
WITH b, r0
DELETE r0 
WITH b
DELETE b
```

When the two lines marked with * is deleted, this error is thrown: Node xxx (the same id as in the error mentioned before) can't be deleted because there are still relationships connected to it. (something along that line)

The data which might be relevant:

```
(id:13557)
primWallAddr    1MEe2mebed8wopvy8xyjjHcEQHUPVJn2UC
multiExist  false
first_seen  2014-09-29T20:03:42
addr_tag_link   null
last_seen   2017-02-03T05:48:14
addr_tag    null
uniqueReferenceAddr 1ERfjthAH9T3PDtFcpkzudha89ABkD9RgSnullnull1MEe2mebed8wopvy8xyjjHcEQHUPVJn2UCfalse
AddId   1ERfjthAH9T3PDtFcpkzudha89ABkD9RgS


b: (id: 13563)
primWallAddr    1KumbRsTcA6UNqU2MHEfqEFnAZYU3w3izR
multiExist  false
first_seen  2014-09-29T20:03:42
addr_tag_link   null
last_seen   2017-02-03T05:48:14
addr_tag    null
uniqueReferenceAddr 1ERfjthAH9T3PDtFcpkzudha89ABkD9RgSnullnull1KumbRsTcA6UNqU2MHEfqEFnAZYU3w3izRfalse
AddId   1ERfjthAH9T3PDtFcpkzudha89ABkD9RgS

(id: 13564)
primWallAddr    1Lsqcv4cg5zUctNi2qwNxMkrv1GeBboSUJ
multiExist  false
first_seen  2014-09-29T20:03:42
addr_tag_link   null
last_seen   2017-02-03T05:48:14
addr_tag    null
uniqueReferenceAddr 1ERfjthAH9T3PDtFcpkzudha89ABkD9RgSnullnull1Lsqcv4cg5zUctNi2qwNxMkrv1GeBboSUJfalse
AddId   1ERfjthAH9T3PDtFcpkzudha89ABkD9RgS
```

All of the nodes shown here are address nodes and all of them have a relationship with one (and only one) wallet node called `:BelongTo`.

Setting the constraint for address and wallet nodes:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (addr:Address) ASSERT addr.uniqueReferenceAddr IS UNIQUE

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (wa:Wallet) ASSERT wa.primWallAddr IS UNIQUE
```

Cypher code for generating the address node:

```
LOAD CSV... as line
MERGE (a:Address {uniqueReferenceAddr:(...)})
ON CREATE SET a.AddId=line[0],...
```

Cypher code for generating the wallet node:

```
LOAD CSV... as line
MERGE (w:Wallet { primWallAddr:line[0]})
ON CREATE SET w.first_seen = line[1]...
```

Cypher code for linking the address node to the corresponding wallet node:

```
MATCH (addr:Address), (wa:Wallet) WHERE addr.primWallAddr=wa.primWallAddr
MERGE (addr)-[r:BelongTo{uniqueReferenceBelongTo:(...)}]->(wa)
ON CREATE SET ...
```

The first query is run after these three queries are run.

Does anyone have an idea what is the reason?

Comment: Can you show example data? P.S. If you want delete node and their relationships you can use `DETACH DELETE a`.

Comment: @stdob-- I am aware of `DETACH DELETE`, but I would prefer not to use ito for now as I am not sure if the other part of my query is working properly. As for example data, as there is a large amount of data involved, so it would be difficult. I could give you the whole code if you want though. (It is a java program which run the cypher code.)

Comment: I can also send you the csv files which triggered this error if you want. (my cypher code load data from csv files first.)

Comment: I am aware of that. But as I said, it is difficult due to the massive data involved. I just figured out a way to get some relevant data, which is the data of three nodes (two of them is the ones in concern here. I don't know which two.)

Comment: Can you show an example of data as a `cypher` to add them?

Comment: Do you mean the format of the data in csv files?

Comment: No, as cypher query with `create` or `merge` this 3 nodes and relationships.

Comment: Do you want the details of the way the properties are set as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142299/discussion-between-stdob-and-aqqqq).

Comment: Correction: I think all three of the node data are relevant data.